# Firebase Cloud Function error: Some values show as undefined?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am designing a game experience for students. The game is like jeopardy and it writes data to the real time database as students progress through the game. At the end of the game I would like to send students an email confirming that they have finished with their score and finish time/date.

I have set up the following code in cloud functions to do so. However, when I run the code off of the trigger, some of the values I read from the database show as undefined - this means that some of the data is not present in the email. What is going on here???

```
   'use strict';

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
       databaseURL: 'https://[MY DATABASE URL]/'
    });

     const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
     const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
     const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
           user: gmailEmail,
           pass: gmailPassword,
         },
       });       

         var email;
         var exitTime;
         var name;
         var userScore;

 exports.gameDoneNotice=functions.database.ref("USERS/{termDate}/GameData/{myUID}/ExitDateTime")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

         const myNumber = context.params.myUID; 
         const myRotation = context.params.termDate; 

            var adminDB = admin.database();

            exitTime = snapshot.val();

            var aRef = adminDB.ref("USERS/" + myRotation + "/GameData/" + myNumber + "/");
            aRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
                email = snapshot.child("eMail").val();
                name = snapshot.child("Name").val();
                userScore = snapshot.child("User Score").val();
            });

            var emailsaad = "MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM";

            console.log(myNumber);
            console.log(myRotation);
            console.log(userScore);
            console.log(name); 


        const APP_NAME = 'WCM-Q DeLib eLearning';        

        const mailOptions = {
             from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
             to: email,
             bcc: emailsaad,
            };  


         mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
         mailOptions.html = `<h3>Dear, ${name}</h3><p>Thank you for completing the Medicine Clerkship EBM game.</p><hr><h4>Your Score: <font color="red">${userScore}</font></h4><h4>Game Completion  Time/Date: <font color="green">${exitTime}</font></h4><hr><p>If you have any questions about the game or your EBM project in this clerkship, don’t hesitate to ask for clarification. Otherwise, your next step is to begin to prepare with your group for your presentation.</p>`;


         try {
             await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
             console.log("eMail was a success");
           } catch(error) {
             console.error('Something has gone horribly wrong, bro!', error);
           }
            return null;

            });
```

I expect that I should be able to read the values I need for email, userScore, etc. from the database and include them in the mailOptions before it is send. However, when I receive the email after the trigger, all of the values from the database read are "undefined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the [`on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) method, which sets a listener "for data changes at a particular location", you need to use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method, which "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type" and **returns a Promise**. You will then be able to use `await` to make the Cloud Function waiting until the promise returned by `once()` resolves and returns its result.

You should therefore modify your code as follows:

```
exports.gameDoneNotice = functions.database
  .ref('USERS/{termDate}/GameData/{myUID}/ExitDateTime')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const myNumber = context.params.myUID;
    const myRotation = context.params.termDate;

    var adminDB = admin.database();

    exitTime = snapshot.val();

    var aRef = adminDB.ref(
      'USERS/' + myRotation + '/GameData/' + myNumber + '/'
    );

    try {
      const snapshot = await aRef.once('value');
      const email = snapshot.child('eMail').val();
      const name = snapshot.child('Name').val();
      const userScore = snapshot.child('User Score').val();

      const emailsaad = 'MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM';

      console.log(myNumber);
      console.log(myRotation);
      console.log(userScore);
      console.log(name);

      const APP_NAME = 'WCM-Q DeLib eLearning';

      const mailOptions = {
        from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
        to: email,
        bcc: emailsaad
      };

      mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
      mailOptions.html = `<h3>Dear, ${name}</h3><p>Thank you for completing the Medicine Clerkship EBM game.</p><hr><h4>Your Score: <font color="red">${userScore}</font></h4><h4>Game Completion  Time/Date: <font color="green">${exitTime}</font></h4><hr><p>If you have any questions about the game or your EBM project in this clerkship, don’t hesitate to ask for clarification. Otherwise, your next step is to begin to prepare with your group for your presentation.</p>`;

      await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
      //Here, actually you could also do return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions); , see the video mentioned below

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Something has gone horribly wrong, bro!', error);
    }
  });
```

---

You may watch the official [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) by Doug Stevenson which explains all these points. In particular the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" and the video about async/await: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jr7pDZ1RAUg